# How to solve duplicated and repeated check in UITableView checklist?

Tags: swift, uitableview, nested-table

I'm setting up survey screen consists of table view so that each cell has table view of checkboxes the problem is that when I check box and scroll down I find that another cell dequeued with checkbox selected.

I have tried to change selection state in prepare for reuse but didn't work

this code for checkbox table view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = taskActionOptionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.TASK_CHOOSE_OPTIONCELL_ID, for: indexPath) as? TaskChooseOptionCell
    if taskResponseActionId == nil {
        taskResponseAction = TaskResponseAction()
    }
    cell?.taskCheckBox.boxType = .circle
    cell?.taskCheckBox.markType = .radio
    cell?.taskCheckBox.boxLineWidth = 2
    cell?.delegate = self
    if cell?.taskCheckBox.checkState == .checked {
        print("checked")
    }
    if taskAction?.taskDependentActions.count != 0 {
        cell?.scoreOperator = taskAction?.taskDependentActions[indexPath.section].scoreOperator
        cell?.scoreNumberValue = taskAction?.taskDependentActions[indexPath.section].scoreNumberValue
    }
    cell?.taskActionOptionScoreValue = taskAction?.taskActionOptions[indexPath.row].taskActionOptionScoreValue
    if cell == nil {
        cell = TaskChooseOptionCell.customCell
    }
    if isDependent {
        cell?.taskDepActionOption = taskDependentActionOptions?[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    } else {
        cell?.taskActionOption = taskActionOptions?[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
}
```

And this for the main table view cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let id = task?.taskActions[indexPath.section].actionTypeId
    let cellType = TaskActionType.allCases.filter {
        return $0.id == id
    }.first
    guard let cellDescType = cellType else { return UITableViewCell() }
    switch cellDescType {
    case .date:
        let dateCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.DATE_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! DateCell
        dateCell.taskMaterial = taskActionsOnMaterialArray[indexPath.row].material
        return dateCell
    case .multiChoice:
        let multiChoiceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.MULTI_CHOOSE_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! MultiChooseCell
        multiChoiceCell.delegate = self
        multiChoiceCell.taskMaterial = task?.taskRestrictedMaterials[indexPath.row]
        multiChoiceCell.taskAction = task?.taskActions[indexPath.section]
        multiChoiceCell.taskActionOptions = Array((task?.taskActions[indexPath.section].taskActionOptions)!)
        return multiChoiceCell
    case .text:
        let textCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.TEXT_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! TextViewCell
        return textCell
    case .singleChoice:
        let singleChoiceCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.SINGLE_CHOICE_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! SingleChoiceCell
        singleChoiceCell.delegate = self
        singleChoiceCell.taskMaterial = task?.taskRestrictedMaterials[indexPath.row]
        singleChoiceCell.taskAction = task?.taskActions[indexPath.section]
        singleChoiceCell.taskActionOptions = Array((task?.taskActions[indexPath.section].taskActionOptions)!)
        return singleChoiceCell
    case .number:
        let numberCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.NUMBER_CELL_ID, for: indexPath) as! NumberCell
        return numberCell
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In your data model you can add a variable like `var done : Bool = " "` and set it to false initially and toggle it on didSelectRow to true or false accordingly and check this variable on the time of setting accessoryType. If its true then set it to `.checked` else set it to `.none`.

Comment: I used custom checkbox lib and I don't call didSelectRow